# Center multiline text vertically in a window, pure winapi and c++

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a window that needs redrawing multiline text on demand, text could be of variable length.
So how to go about doing this ?

This is what I have for now and it doesn't work.

```
               RECT rc;

               GetWindowRect ( hwnd, &rc );



               int rectHeight = DrawText( hMemDc, text.c_str(), text.size(), &rc, DT_CALCRECT );                    // Get formating rectangle height


               int windowHight = rc.bottom - rc.top;
               int windowWidth = rc.right - rc.left;


               int yTop = rc.top + (  ( windowHight - rectHeight ) / 2  );
               int yBottom = yTop + rectHeight;

               int xLeft = rc.left + 20;
               int xRight = rc.right - 20;


               rc.top       = yTop;
               rc.bottom    = yBottom;
               rc.left      = xLeft;
               rc.right     = xRight;


               DrawText( hMemDc, text.c_str(), text.size(), &rc, DT_LEFT | DT_WORDBREAK );
```

Comment: There's a `DT_VCENTER` flag.

Comment: @chris It works on single line only.

Comment: You need to get the rect it will use by first drawing with `DT_CALCRECT`, then centre the calculated rect in your window and draw normally.

Comment: Use DT_CENTER, it works on multiline text.

Comment: @RogerRowland: that is not the same thing as drawing the text truely centered. The rect may be centered in the window, but the text within the rect won't be centered.

Comment: @RogerRowland That's exactly what I did, see the code above.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I missed that - @RemyLebeau is giving better advice (as usual ;-))

Comment: @RemyLebeau breaking the lines ? You mean based on character count ? What if we want to subclass(oop) the control with different height and width ?

Comment: @StudentX: I mean splitting the text on line breaks, max character count that fits within the rectangle width, punctuation, etc - just like DT_WORDBREAK does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code. First, you need to specify `DT_WORDBREAK` in the `DT_CALCRECT` call otherwise it won't wrap the text to fit the available width.

```
int rectHeight = DrawText( hMemDc, text.c_str(), text.size(), &rc,
  DT_CALCRECT|DT_WORDBREAK );
```

Second, the `DT_CALCRECT` call will override the `rc` variable with calculated rect, so your window height will be wrong and your centering won't work. Either save the `rc` variable before the `DT_CALCRECT` call, or call `GetWindowRect` again afterwards.

```
GetWindowRect ( hwnd, &rc );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) Didn't know DT_CALCRECT call will override the rc variable.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem drawing some debug lines to help me with the code:

```
                {
                    CPen p;
                    p.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 0, RGB(0,0,255));
                    pDrawDC->SelectObject(&p);

                    pDrawDC->MoveTo(rc.TopLeft());
                    pDrawDC->LineTo(rc.BottomRight());
                }

                CRect rdebug(rc);

                int height= pDrawDC->DrawText(sLabel, &rdebug, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_CALCRECT);

                {
                    CPen p;
                    p.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 0, RGB(0,255,0));
                    pDrawDC->SelectObject(&p);

                    pDrawDC->MoveTo(rdebug.TopLeft());
                    pDrawDC->LineTo(rdebug.BottomRight());
                }

                int center_y= rc.CenterPoint().y;
                rc.top= center_y - height / 2;
                rc.bottom= center_y + height /2;

                {
                    CPen p;
                    p.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 0, RGB(255,0,0));
                    pDrawDC->SelectObject(&p);

                    pDrawDC->MoveTo(rc.TopLeft());
                    pDrawDC->LineTo(rc.BottomRight());
                }

                pDrawDC->DrawText(sLabel, rc, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_WORDBREAK);
```

Notice the rDebug, CPen, LineTo and MoveTo lines are only for debug purposes.

I've got the following image:

[image: debug image]

Now, without the debug part, I could reduce the source-code footprint to:

```
                int height= pDrawDC->DrawText(sLabel, CRect(rc), DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_WORDBREAK | DT_CALCRECT);

                int center_y= rc.CenterPoint().y;
                rc.top= center_y - height / 2;
                rc.bottom= center_y + height /2;

                pDrawDC->DrawText(sLabel, rc, DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER | DT_WORDBREAK);
```