# CDC::DrawText multi-line and rotated

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to draw rotated multi-line test in win32. I'm using DrawText with DT_WORDBREAK to break the text into lines within a bounding box, and defining a XFORM transform matrix to manipulate the world transform before drawing so I can draw the text rotated:

```
/* desiredOrigin - point around which to apply the rotation (rotated text 'topleft' corner)
   textboxSize - desired horizontal textbox size (I'm assuming this should get rotated by drawtext)
   pDC is setup with a font with lfEscapement = 900 (odd that I have to do this, clearly the transform doesn't work like I expected)
*/
void DrawRotatedText(CDC* pDC, CString text, CPoint desiredOrigin, CSize textboxSize, double rotationRads)
{
    XFORM oldTransform;
    pDC->GetWorldTransform(&oldTransform);

    XFORM textTransform = oldTransform;

    float dSin = (float)sin(rotationRads);
    float dCos = (float)cos(rotationRads);

    //setup rotation components from desired angle
    textTransform.eM11 = dCos;
    textTransform.eM12 = dSin;
    textTransform.eM21 = -dSin;
    textTransform.eM22 = dCos;
    //setup translation from desiredtext origin
    textTransform.eDx = (FLOAT)desiredOrigin.x;
    textTransform.eDy = (FLOAT)desiredOrigin.y;

    pDC->SetWorldTransform(&textTransform);

    CRect bounds(CPoint(0, 0), textboxSize);
    pDC->DrawText(text, bounds, DT_TOP | DT_CENTER | DT_WORDBREAK);

    pDC->SetWorldTransform(&oldTransform);
}
```

This isn't working at all, and I'm not sure if it's because I did something wrong or DrawText doesn't work with world transforms..

I'm trying to draw a 90 degrees rotated text starting at the bottom left of the page (along the left edge). What I get is what seems correctly rotated text, but near the top of the page (going off screen). As I expand the window height, the text starts moving right around the x-axis, and stay stationary along the y-axis (well the visible text does change, but that should be the line wrap redrawing at different textbox widths).

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I'll gladly provide more detail if needed.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31756700/383779. May be you need to do a `DT_CALCRECT` firstly.

Comment: You also need to set the graphics mode of the device context to advanced:

int oldgm = pDC->SetGraphicsMode(GM_ADVANCED);